# How to send data file into an application through python

Tags: python, subprocess

I read about the subprocess module and I found out that it is possible to send data-file (txt) into  application that has been called through the subprocess module in python like:

```
import subprocess

 f = open('data-file.txt', 'r')
 with subprocess.Popen('runsoftware.exe', stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
           stdin=f)as p:
     stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
     sleep(1)
     subprocess.Popen.kill(p)
```

but nothing happens. Is there any better way of sending data-file into an application?

Comment: You're opening the file in write mode, which will empty the content of the file on disk... Meaning, you've passed an empty file

Comment: You opened the file for writing (`'w'`), which promptly erases the file.  If you want to feed input, open the file for reading.

Comment: oh that was  typo error it actually 'r'

Answer (score 0):

#### You a erasing the file via opening in write mode.

```py
import subprocess

 f = open('data-file.txt', 'r')
 with subprocess.Popen('runsoftware.exe', stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
           stdin=f)as p:
     stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
     sleep(1)
     subprocess.Popen.kill(p)
```

Should send a file. Also you should **close** the file at the end or your code.